# Office 365 App Error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, office-365-develop-tool, napa

Hello I'm new on Office 365/SharePoint 2013 Apps development, as first test project I have created an Outlook App (Mail app for Office), I didn't edit the simple code generated by NAPA, normally it will work, but when I deploy the app I get this error :

> **App Error** Something went wrong and we couldn't start this app. Please try again later or contact your system administrator.

[image]

After some debugging, via the F12 Tools, I find that the https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.0/hosted/office.js is not available! Is there a solution for this problem ?

**EDIT :** 
The site is available over http but not over https, then I tried to use it but it still not working:

> The page at
>   'https://grindi-81a84eec62----.sharepoint.com/FirstMailApp/App/Home/Home.htm…#path=/mail'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
>   'http://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.0/hosted/office.js': this
>   content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: Hey I had the same issue with my computer. I wasted my time on it for ﻿many days but finally I got a solution from this link http://www.microsoftliveassist.com/office-365-installation-error-something-went-wrong/﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : the issue is only happen when I debug my app in Napa, and at the same time I'm signed in to MSDN sites.
If I logout from the MSDN, the issue is solved.